# why is the css opacity fade out not working

Tags: html, css, fade

I want to fade one word out and then fade another one in but the problem is it seems to come back

I tried to put the opacity from one to zero but it doesn't work

```css
    animation: fadeout 5s;
}
@keyframes fadeout
{

from{opacity: 1;}
to {opacity: 0;

}

}
.fade-in{
    animation: fadein 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein
{

from{opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}

}
html{background-color: white}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>welcom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welc.css" >
</head>
<body>
    <center>
<font class='fade-out' size="30"> hello </font>

<font class='fade-in' size="30"> do you like pandas?</font>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the (hello) to fully fade out and for the (do you like pandas) to fade in

Comment: you're missing a close bracket after  to {opacity:0;

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the opacity property with the value 0 in the fade-out class, since it is the final result.

```css
.fade-out{ 
 animation: fadeout 5s;
 opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes fadeout
{

from{opacity: 1;}
to {opacity: 0;}

}
.fade-in{
  animation: fadein 5s;
}
@keyframes fadein
{

from{opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;}

}
html{background-color: white}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>welcom</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="welc.css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
    <font class='fade-out' size="30"> hello </font>

    <font class='fade-in' size="30"> do you like pandas?</font>
        </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating an animation, sometimes you need to specify the fill mode. That is telling your animated element, which styling to keep after the animation ends.

You can specify the fill mode using the [`animation-fill-mode property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

[`animation-fill-mode property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) can be set to :

- animation-fill-mode : forwards;
- animation-fill-mode :  backwards;
- animation-fill-mode :  both;
- animation-fill-mode :  none;

By setting to forwards, the element will keep the styling you specified in the 100% of your animation.

By setting to backwards, the element will keep the styling you specified in the 0%.

Therefore, you can add

```
.fade-out{
    animation: fadeout 5s;
    animation-fill-mode : forwards;
}
```

and it should work.

Hope that helps.